# Python Selenium, how to store logon session for scraping site behind authentication

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am having trouble storing my logon session with Selenium to scrape a site behind authentication.  I am trying with cookies, because what I read is that almost all sites use cookies.  Here's what I've done:

```
driver = Firefox()


def logon(drvr):
    drvr.get('https://www.site/to/scrape/logon')
    wait = WebDriverWait(drvr, 10)
    elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'memberId')))
    elem.send_keys('xxxx', Keys.RETURN)
    elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
    elem.send_keys('xxxx', Keys.RETURN)
    elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class='
        '"sub-label font-narrow"]')))
    ver = elem.get_attribute('aria-label')
    if ' '.join(ver.split()) == 'phone number ending in 1 3 6 1':
        elem.click()
    value = input('Enter security code: ')
    elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'inputValue')))
    elem.send_keys(value, Keys.RETURN)


def main(drvr):
    cookies = drvr.get_cookies()
    print(cookies)
    for cookie in cookies:
        drvr.add_cookie(cookie)
    drvr.get('https://www.site/behind/logon')


logon(driver)
main(driver)
```

I can log in successfully, but the above code kicks me back out to the logon page.  Selenium's not storing the session.  Have I done something wrong?  If the site uses another method of storing the session, how can I find that out?  What I've read is that most sites use cookies.

Comment: you don't need to get the cookies and then set them again... once you login the cookies will be set.  (However, you do need a bit of a pause because the server will send a "set cookie" header... then the browser will store the cookie... this takes a small amount of time, but you've used another .get() there without waiting.)

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins.  I've read similar on another help thread, so my code would work, but is redundant?  So, I need to wait for the cookies to be stored.  About how long should I tell the script to sleep?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: The best way is to use a webdriverwait to wait for an expectedcondition that will only occur on the content that appears after login.  Usually the server will respond with "setcookie"... then a redirect (or in the case of single-page app, some return value that tells the javascript to update the DOM...)  For instance, an "account" or "login/logout" type button.  Getting the cookies in your code is not necessary.

Comment: Great, @pcalkins.  I'll see what I can come up with once I set down this other script I'm working on.  About how long does the browser take to set cookies?

Comment: under 1 second... but the server may take longer.  Server response depends on a lot of factors.  They may also be doing things to avoid timing attacks.... use at minimum a 5 second wait time in your webdriverwait.  (it doesn't hurt to go higher if the login is correct.  It'll take only the amount of needed for the expectedcondition to appear.)

Comment: Well, I've managed to do what I wanted to.  Turns out I don't need to fetch each web page behind the login with `get()`.  Selenium can work with each page as it loads it.  So, you just load the page and work on the elements from there.